# Why is there latency with ORMLite when I print results?

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite but when I do prints after deletes for exemple I still see the deleted lines, for exemple:

```
demandesDao = db.getDemandesDao();
final List<Demandes> demandes = demandesDao.queryForAll();
DeleteBuilder<Demandes,Integer> deleteBuilder = demandesDao.deleteBuilder();
deleteBuilder.where().eq("contactWebId", 15515);
deleteBuilder.delete();

System.out.println(demandes);
```

Comment: @Gray sorry i did an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using ORMLite but when I do prints after deletes for example I still see the deleted lines

That's correct.  The `DeleteBuilder` only removes rows from the database.  Any local collections that you have already queried for are not affected.  In your case, your `demandes` list was queried *before* the delete was performed.  If you run another `queryForAll()` method, you should see that the rows have been removed from the database.